# How to change the tag of the default Errors decorator within Zend_Form?

Tags: zend-form, decorator, zend-decorators

I'm trying to change the tag of the Errors decorator, currently it's:

```
<ul class="errors">
  <li>error message</li>
</ul>
```

I'd like to remove the `<ul>` wrapper and change the `<li>` by ie `<p>`.

I tried a lot of things, but can't get it to work..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

You can't change the default tags of the Errors decorators because it calls the default views helper `Zend_View_Helper_FormErrors` and you've no way to pass paramaters.

So you'll to write your own Decorator & View Helper.

I did something similar to wrap errors into `<label>` elements

I created `LabelledErrors` decorator which calls a `FormLabelledErrors` helper and reset the default decorators, replacing the Errors decorator by my own.